# Office 2007 in Windows Update when Office 2007 is not installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-office, windows-update

When I updated Windows 7 today, I noticed that it included several updates for Office 2007. However, I only have Office 2003 installed. Are these Office 2007 updates (a) for Office 2003, (b) for Visual Studio 2008, or (c) a figment of Bill Gates's imagination?

Comment: I have only OpenOffice installed and I still get the Office 2007 updates listed. So +1 from me.

Comment: I also keep seeing spam protection updates for Outlook, and I don't have it installed... +1 from me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any of the viewers or compatibility packs installed, that might trigger updates associated with the newer version of Office.  Upon getting certain attachments in Exchange I was prompted to download a compatibility pack in order to view the document.  After this I would see 2007 related Updates in my 2003 Office install.  I would also see the updates when I only had Visio Viewer installed.

Link to the Compatibility Pack which may be installed:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=941B3470-3AE9-4AEE-8F43-C6BB74CD1466&displaylang=en

From the actual support text -
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=fb457536-26c5-428b-97e4-1fc13718266e

> This update applies to the following products:  The 2007 Microsoft Office suite and the **Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack**

I had Visio Viewer installed, then later deleted, and sill would require the Update.  I'm assuming this is because some DLL's were left behind.

Answer (score 0):

I have Office 2003 and started getting updates for Office 2007 after installing the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack. When looking at the associated KB articles for 7 recent security updates, 2 did apply to the compatibility pack (as well as Office 2007), which I installed. The other 5 applied only to Office 2007, which I did not install.

If you are not inclined to click "More information" for every security update offered, you are probably better off installing superfluous security updates than not having those that apply to you - they are usually relatively small, and are not likely to do any harm.